# Django Query : how do I find the maximum time duration from start and end time fields?

Tags: sql, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset

Here is my Django model:

```
class Shift(models.Model):
        worker = models.OneToOneField('Worker',null=True)
        date = models.DateField(null=True)
        shiftTime = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="N/A")
        timeIn = models.TimeField(null=True)
        timeOut = models.TimeField(null=True)
```

I need to find a worker who spent the maximum amount of time in the office in a given date range. How do I calculate the time duration from timeIn and timeOut field in Django query?

Edit: I don't want to use another attribute **duration** because that seems redundant. Is there any other way to do it than using raw query or duration attribute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Select Query Time Diff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698486/django-select-query-time-diff)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django 1.10 introduced the ability to [natively do date/time diffs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#database-backend-api) through the ORM. This query would get you the longest shift:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F

longest_shift = Shift.objects.annotate(shift_length=ExpressionWrapper(
                                           F('timeOut') - F('timeIn'),
                                           output_field=DurationField()))\.
                                           order_by('-shift_length').first()
```

You can add a filter for a specific date range as required by adding a `filter()` clause before `annotate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the objects and get the maximum duration between the timeIn and timeOut.

```
def get_largest_time_diff():
    shift_objs = Shift.objects.all()
    time_diff = 0

    if shift_objs:
       time_diff = shift_objs[0].timeOut - shift_objs[0].timeIn

       for tm in shift_objs[1:]:
           if time_diff < tm.timeOut - tm.timeIn:
               time_diff = tm.timeOut - tm.timeIn

    return time_diff
```